# What's the difference between these lambda suppliers?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, supplier

i just wanted to know if there is any difference between these two Supplier statements:

```
() -> this.enabled
this::enabled
```

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: The first is supplying the value of a field; the second is supplying the result of invoking a method. Did you mean to write `() -> this.enabled()` for the first, to make them do the same?

Comment: No, I was just trying to understand the code of a project on github. Now I saw that the first was supplying a field and the second was supplying a method. Thanks :)